# Swiftui + Firestore + CombineLatest keep publishing data

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore, combine, combinelatest

I'm trying to merges two published object from query of two different collections to make a single published array using `combineLatest`.

```
import Combine
import Firebase

class FirestoreViewModel: ObservableObject {
    let userId: String
    
    @Published var aList: [DocumentA]? = nil
    @Published var bList: [DocumentB]? = nil
    
    init(userId: String, listenForChanges: Bool = false)    {
        
        // Get the user
        if (listenForChanges)   {
            self.loadA()
            self.loadB()
        }
    }
    
    var cList: AnyPublisher<[DocumentC]?, Never> {
        return Publishers.CombineLatest(
            $aList.map { (aList) -> [DocumentC]?  in
                guard let aList = aList else { return nil }
                return aList.map {a in
                    DocumentC(from: a)
                }
            },
            $bList.map { (bList) -> [DocumentC]?  in
                guard let bList = bList else { return nil }
                return bList.map { n in
                    DocumentC(from: b)
                }
            })
            .map { (aList, bList) -> [DocumentC]?  in
                
                if (aList == nil && bList == nil) { return nil }
                
                var cList: [DocumentC] = []
                
                if let aList = aList {
                    cList.append(contentsOf: aList)
                }
                
                if let bList = bList {
                    cList.append(contentsOf: bList)
                }
                return cList
            }
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
    
    private func loadA() {
        
        // Start listening
        Firestore.firestore().collection("colA").addSnapshotListener { (snapshot, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("DEBUG: Unable to get user data: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }
            
            // Invalid data return
            guard let snapshot = snapshot else {
                print("DEBUG: null data returned")
                self.aList = nil
                return
            }
            
            // Update the info
            var aList: [DocumentA] = []
            snapshot.documents.forEach { document in
                let aData = document.data()
                guard !aData.isEmpty else {
                    return
                }
                aList.append(DocumentA(from: aData)
                
            }
            self.aList = aList
        }
    }
    
    private func loadB() {
        
        // Start listening
        Firestore.firestore().collection("colB").addSnapshotListener { (snapshot, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("DEBUG: Unable to get user data: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }
            
            // Invalid data return
            guard let snapshot = snapshot else {
                print("DEBUG: null data returned")
                self.bList = nil
                return
            }
            
            // Update the info
            var bList: [DocumentB] = []
            snapshot.documents.forEach { document in
                let bData = document.data()
                guard !bData.isEmpty else {
                    return
                }
                bList.append(DocumentB(from: bData))
                
            }
            self.userUnits = userUnits
        }
    }
}
```

When I debug, I can see that `aList` and `bList` are published once, however, the `cList` keeps been published eventually eating all the memory...

The `cList` is consumed via a onReceive statement in the view, which output each item.

Would anybody be able to tell me why the `combineLatest` keeps on publishing `cList`, though there are no fresh `aList` or `bList` published ?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show the view consuming `cList`? My guess is that the view is updated whenever `cList` emits a value, which causes the `onReceive` to get `cList` again. It's a computed property, so anytime you access it a new publisher is generated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In all likelihood, you have a situation where you update the view with values just received from `cList`, which causes the `body` to be recomputed, which causes another `onReceive(vm.cList) {...}`, which causes a ***new*** publisher to be returned by the computed property `cList`, which emits the values again and repeats the cycle.

Here's an simplified example of what I mean:

```
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
   @Published var aList: [Int] = [1,2]

   var cList: AnyPublisher<Int, Never> {
      $aList.map { $0 + $0 }.eraseToAnyPublisher()
   }
}

struct ContentView: View {
   @StateObject var vm = ViewModel()
   @State var list: [Int] = []

   var body: some View {
      VStack {
         ForEach(list, id: \.self) { v in
            Text("\(v)")
         }
      }
      .onReceive(vm.cList) { self.list = $0 }
   }
}
```

To avoid that, `cList` shouldn't be a computed property. It could just be a lazy-ly assigned constant:

```
lazy var cList: AnyPublisher<Int, Never> = 
   $alist.map { $0 + $0 }
         .eraseToAnyPublisher()
```